# What would be the major product of isobutyl alcohol + BF3 with benzene?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I'm having trouble understanding the mechanism for isobutyl alcohol +  BF3 with benzene. I cant figure out the major product

Answer (score 2):

Two things to keep in mind:

1. $\ce{BF3}$ is a Lewis acid, and we would expect it to form a carbocation with an alcohol. The carbocation would then attack the benzene ring as an electrophile.
2. That carbocation might not be isobutyl cation. You should be able to see that such a cation would rearrange to the more stable, tertiary, tert-butyl cation with a facile hydride shift. You should identify the major product accordingly.

Carbocation rearrangement is a significant issue with Friedel-Crafts alkylation. F-C acylation tends to give a more controllable product.